# Play Framework WebSocket reject connection with custom error code

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework

```
def socket: WebSocket = {
    WebSocket.acceptOrResult[Message, Message] { implicit request: RequestHeader =>
      serviceUserIdentity.getUserIdentity(request) map {
        case Some(userIdentityPlay) if userIdentityPlay.hasValidLicense =>
          Right(
            ActorFlow.actorRef(out =>
              ActorWSServer.props(out)
            )
          )
        case Some(_) =>
          Left(Results(4403)) //invalid user
        case None =>
          Left(Results(4401)) //session expired
      } recover {
        case exception: Exception =>
          Left(InternalServerError)
      }
    }
  }
```

This `CloseEvent` is what I get back from the server when the user doesn't have a valid license or he's session is expired.

```
CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1006, reason: "", type: "close", …}
```

It looks like `Result` Http code (4403) is getting overwritten to 1006.

The result that I am expecting:

```
CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 4403, reason: "", type: "close", …}
```

Is there a way to achieve this at `WebSocket.accept`?
Or a workaround using `play.api.http.websocket.CloseMessage`?

Comment: Based on this [github issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1948) I think this might be a bug in play, it looks like 1006 should never be returned.